Prefix user login_name and validate it is unique on Registration
I want to add a static prefix to each new user who registers.
I do it using the pre_user_login hook
Example:
function prefix_user_on_registration($username)
{
    if (!str_starts_with($username, 'prefix-')) {
        return 'prefix-' . $username;
    }

    return $username;
}
    
add_filter( 'pre_user_login', 'prefix_user_on_registration' );

But this way the validation if the username is unique is done before the prefix happens.
I need a way to validate the username with the prefix.
Any ideas?

that filter wouldn't be best for this, can you add some context for why you're prefixing the users but letting users login without typing the prefix? Note that 2 users in the users table can't have the same username, if you tried the database would reject it and creation/editing of the user would fail as that column is designated as unique

No, the validation of the uniqueness happens AFTER this filter. Which is logical, because there is no point to check for uniqueness first and then allow a filter to change the username, possibly destroying the uniqueness. The only thing happening before this filter is sanitiation.

@TomJNowell Acorind to WP docs: This filter is called before the user is created or updated.. So I will have to modify the code to check if the user already exists and if not, then to prefix its username. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_login/

@cjbj I can confirm that the validation was made before this hook. Here's why:
I created a user with the username test then I tried to register a new user test but this time prefixing it with prefix-, The error that I get is: Error: Could not register you… please contact the site admin! instead of  Error: This username is already registered. Please choose another one.

@mr.d Ah, I see what is going wrong here

note that if the code in the question did work, it would continually prefix the user, leading to usernames such as prefix-prefix-prefix-test after 3 logins etc It would be more efficient to check if the username contains the prefix, rather than querying the database and performing a raw SQL query. You also misunderstood the uniqueness comment I made, this is not a check in a PHP filter, it's an attribute on the DB column performed by MySQL and the database table schema. Even if PHP performs no checks of any kind and you deliberately try to add 2 users with the same username, it won't work.

@TomJNowell Thank You for the suggestion about the database call. I have modified the function code to check if the username starts with the prefix and if not return the prefix + username. About the unique username, I understand that the field in the database is unique and there will be no two users with the same name, my concern is that the error on the registration page is not descriptive enough for the one who is registering to know that should use another username.

The usual way to create a user goes with the register_new_user function. This function offers no filter for the user name. It just checks for uniqueness with username_exists. To actually create the user register_new_user then calls wp_create_user, which in turn calls wp_insert_user.
The latter function contains the pre_user_login filter. Then it calls username_exists again, because the filter may have nullified the uniqueness. If his results in an error, the user is not created and the register_new_user function will give you Error: Could not register you… please contact the site admin!
So, if you register a user 'test' it will pass the first username_exists, move on to the filter, be modified to 'prefix-test' and then pass username_exists once more. If you register a user 'test' again, it will pass the first username_exists, because there is no user 'test', but after the filter it is renamed 'prefix-test', which does exist. So it will fail the second username_exists.
You can get around this by abusing the only filter that is available before the uniqueness test in register_new_user. That is in sanitize_user. You can add a prefix there, but beware that this function is called in wp_insert_user as well, so you will want to add the prefix only when it isn't already there.

Thank You for the detailed reply! I appreciate it!
Could you give me a simple example of how to use sanitize_user?

the same as your current filter, but not with pre_user_login but sanitize user as the hook

Oh, I see. I have found the documentation for the function sanitize_user(), but there is also a hook. Anyway, I have tried but I get this error:
Error: This username is invalid because it uses illegal characters. Please enter a valid username.

Yes, that's the risk if you hack into sanitize_user. If you introduce an illegal character in the username at that point, it will be marked as invalid later on by the function validate_username. This function calls sanitize_user once more to see if the username is still the same as the sanitized username generated earlier on.
